# 1. Stray `space' in KNUTH's `\primes` macro 2. Formatting macros for logical clarity

Tags: plain-tex

1. The `\primes` macro in `Knuth's TeXBook (Version 3.0 1996)` in `Chapter 20: Definitions (also called Macros)` page 218, produces a stray `space` after the `3`, as in  `2, 3 , 5, 7, 11, ...`. I have given up finding where it comes from.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   % RN. 13 Dec 2018
   \begin{document}
   \newif\ifprime \newif\ifunknown % boolean variables 
   \newcount\n \newcount\p \newcount\d \newcount\a % integer variables
   \def\primes#1{2,~3% assume that #1 is at least 3 
   \n=#1 \advance\n by-2 % n more to go 
   \p=5% odd primes starting with p 
   \loop\ifnum\n>0 \printifprime\advance\p by2 \repeat} 
   \def\printp{, % we will invoke \printp if p is prime 
   \ifnum\n=1 and~\fi % ‘and’ precedes the last value 
   \number\p \advance\n by -1 } 
   \def\printifprime{\testprimality \ifprime\printp\fi} 
   \def\testprimality{{\d=3 \global\primetrue 
   \loop\trialdivision \ifunknown\advance\d by2 \repeat}} 
   \def\trialdivision{\a=\p \divide\a by\d 
   \ifnum\a>\d \unknowntrue\else\unknownfalse\fi 
   \multiply\a by\d 
   \ifnum\a=\p \global\primefalse\unknownfalse\fi}

   \def\N{10}
   The first \N\ prime numbers are: \primes{\N~}.

   \end{document}
   ```
2. To enhance my ability to read code (including my own) without the help of yellow, green and blue texters and a fat black permanent marker, I am in a habit of formatting it for logical clarity, mainly by using indentation. In the case of `Saint Knuth's` `\primes` this results in the following, but any hopes to spot the renegade `space` that way were ill-founded:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   % RN. 13 Dec 2018
   \begin{document}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   %   variables:
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
   % boolean:
   \newif\ifprime
   \newif\ifunknown 
   % integer: 
   \newcount\n
   \newcount\p
   \newcount\d
   \newcount\a
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   %   the macros:
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
   \def\prime#1%
   {
       \n=#1 \advance\n by -2 % n more to go 
       \p=5% odd primes starting with p 
       \loop \ifnum\n>0 
           \printifprime\advance\p by 2 
       \repeat
   } 

   \def\printp
   {%
       , % we will invoke \printp if p is prime 
       \ifnum\n=1 and~\fi  % ‘and’ precedes the last value 
       \number\p \advance\n by -1 
   } 

   \def\printifprime
   {%
       \testprimality 
       \ifprime 
           \printp 
       \fi
   } 

   \def\testprimality
   {%
       {%
           \d=3 \global\primetrue 
           \loop
               \trialdivision 
               \ifunknown \advance\d by 2 
           \repeat
       }%
   } 

   \def\trialdivision
   {%
       \a=\p \divide\a by \d 
       \ifnum\a>\d 
           \unknowntrue
       \else
           \unknownfalse
       \fi 
       \multiply\a by \d 
       \ifnum\a=\p 
           \global\primefalse\unknownfalse
       \fi
   }

   \def\N{10}
   The first \N\ prime numbers are: \primes{\N~}.

   \end{document}
   ```

NOTE: In formatting the code I introduced `% characters` as required to achieve the desired expansion purely by trial and error. Any general advise or guidelines for the indentation of `plain-TeX` code which will avoid making a complete mess of the final printed output are welcome.

Comment: Relevant quote from [Knuth interview](https://books.google.com/books?id=nneBa6-mWfgC&pg=PA597): _When I put in the calculation of prime numbers into the TeX manual I was not thinking of this as the way to use TeX. I was thinking, "Oh, by the way, look at this: dogs can stand on their hind legs and TeX can calculate prime numbers."_ :-)

Comment: Well, his programming style was somewhere characterised as "idiosyncratic", and so is he.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\primes{\N~}` That's your spurious space right there.  Remove the `~`.  This is not `expl3`, i.e. `~` is not a regular space but `\def~{\penalty\@M \ }`.

When you request `\primes{\N~}` this expands to

```
2,~3% assume that #1 is at least 3
\n=\N~ \advance\n by-2 % n more to go
%    ^
```

which further expands to

```
2,~3% assume that #1 is at least 3
\n=10\penalty\@M \  \advance\n by-2 % n more to go
%    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    will not be collapsed
```

which is exactly the space you see after the 3.